# hyperlink <a href> using POST Method instead of GET method

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

As i know, all hyperlink working as `GET` method. But I wanna make a hyperlink which should be in `POST` method instead of `GET` Method `<a href='targetpage'>click</a>`

**Note: I don't want to submit any form. I SHOULD BE ONLY `<a>` TAG**

So is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do it with a simple `<a>`-tag. You would need to either to it with a form or with Ajax (but that wouldn't redirect the user). POST is for sending data, so having a POST without any data doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That's like asking a cat to be a dog; you can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post method can only be used by form data if called by html.

So the only solution would be to make a form and hide the inputs which you want to post, and submit the post to the url you want to.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this,

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="target.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" /> 
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit(); return false;">click here</a> 
</form>
```

Comment: _"Note: I don't want to submit any form"_